# What's difference between these two jar files?

Tags: java, jar

I'm totally new to Java. I'm learning Stanford CS-106A. In this course, they provided acm.jar and yahtzeelib.jar to finish the assignment. I've found an answer on Internet, why he imports acm at the beginning of his code. But when he wants to use methods in yahtzeelib.jar, he can directly use them without importing yahtzeelib.

So my question is why there's a difference between using these two jar files?(one must be imported and the other can directly be used in the code)

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJdl.png)

Comment: A bit hard to say without showing us the code ...

Comment: jars contain compiled classes and those classes contains methods which you will like to use.Except for java.lang package classes,other classes need to be imported (always)

Comment: Sorry, i think i've already add an image, but i don't know why you cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import Classes to use them in Java, they just need to be on the [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

If a class called "Baz" lives in the package "foo.bar", then you can use it right away by the name "foo.bar.Baz".

Should you "import foo.bar.Baz;", then you can refer to that class by the simple name "Baz".

My guess is that the classes from .jar #2 is in the Default package.

Comment: yes, i just found out that #2 is in the Default package. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried to import .jar#2, but it failed and it says"cannot be resolved". Does that mean i cannot import this kind of file when it's in the default package?

Comment: You do not import files, you import names from packages. You need to place jars on the classpath, and once you have done that - all classes therein will be available by full name (this.is.a.package.ClassName). Use imports if you want to be able to use the short name (ClassName).